# How can I use an Angular app into child routes of another Angular app?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-module

I'd like to load an Angular app using lazy-loading (when a specific route is hit by users) into another Angular app
Shall I compile the first app in order to be used into the second one or what?

Routing-Module of the app to nest into an Angular app:

```
const upgradeRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '/upgrade',
    component: HelloComponent
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/upgrade', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(upgradeRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class UpgradeRoutingModule { }
```

Module of the app to nest into an Angular app

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HelloComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    UpgradeRoutingModule
  ],
  exports: [
    UpgradeModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class UpgradeModule { }
```

App module where I want to use (with lazy loading) the first one described in a child routes:

```
import {UpgradeModule} from '../../node_modules/module-upgrade/src/app/app.module'  

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
     ...
   ],
   import: [ UpgradeModule ]
});
```

1) I'd like to understand if that is correct, and/or there is another way to do it.

2) Another problem is that the **child app** uses Angualr 6, whereas the second/main one uses Angular 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either:

- Don't bootstrap your child app and use it as a submodule (that requires that you upgrade the main app to Angular 6, which requires at least to refactor your RxJS operators calls, and probably some minor other things),
- Or just configure your web server to serve your child app on a specific URL. In that case your two apps won't be able to share any state (except global namespace, cookies and localStorage) or
  Angular Component/Service/Directive/Pipe

Comment: you could also take a look at https://angular.io/guide/elements - but of course this is anything but a straight-forward approach

Comment: But how can I load an external module (Angular app) in order to use in my App when a user hit a specific url?

Comment: You must include your child app in the main app build, following this guide : https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules, but your child app won't be bootstrapped, then won't be able to run as a standalone app

Comment: I'd like to run that "sub app" in a child-route doing something like that
`{
  path: 'specific',
  loadChildren: 'app.module'
}`

Comment: yeah this is totally feasible, what I mean is that you won't be able to load **the child app only**, because it will depend on the main app

Comment: I did what's in that url, but I'm getting some error
_Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 194:50 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol NgModule in /Users/username/Dev/Work/Essence/upgrade-module/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts, resolving symbol UpgradeModule in /Users/username/Dev/Work/Essence/upgrade-module/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol UpgradeModule in /Users/username/Dev/Work/Essence/upgrade-
module/src/app/app.module.ts_

Comment: There must be a mistake in your `@NgModule` declaration. If you need help on how to create lazy modules I suggest you write a new question with the appropriate details

Comment: But I thought this was the main question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174265/discussion-between-youkouleley-and-donovant).